# How to play videos of different formats in html using video tag

Tags: css, html, video

I have a page where I need to display videos with different extensions.

Example: `.mp4`, `.wmv`

```
<video width="100%" controls>
   <source data-ng-src="{{video.url}}" type="video/*">
        Your browser does not support this video.
</video>
```

I just put a star but it is not playing my video.Showing an empty screen.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In case you need it to support multiple types of videos, you must add multiple `source` of those videos. The browser picks the appropriate one to play.

And moreover, your code doesn't contain the `src` attribute.

```html
<video width="100%" controls>
  <source src="http://www.educationalquestions.com/video/ELL_PART_5_768k.wmv" type="video/wmv">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: @downvoter I would appreciate if you have commented regarding the problem with my answer.